# Remove "-" from apache rewrite parameter

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, get

I'm using mod_rewrite and want to do this :

```
RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]*)-(.*)-(.*)$ pages/page_item.php?id=$1-&name=$2-&firstname=$3 [QSA,L]
```

to become  this

```
item/25-Foo-Bar
```

But when I var_dump the $_get parameter through PHP, I get this :

```
array (size=3)
  'id' => string '25-' (length=4)
  'prenom' => string 'Foo-' (length=4)
  'nom' => string 'Bar' (length=7)
```

The first 2 paramter includes the "-" character.
How to avoid this ?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It includes the `-` because you are *explicitly* placing it in the rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]*)-(.*)-(.*)$ pages/page_item.php?id=$1-&name=$2-&firstname=$3 [QSA,L]
#--------------------------------------------------------------^--------^---
```

Remove those, and you'll get the result you expect.

You can improve your regular expression though. Instead of using the greedy `(.*)`, I would recommend using `([^-]+)`. The expression `[^-]+` means to match all characters up to but not including the next `-`.

So your final result looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]*)-([^-]+)-(.*)$ pages/page_item.php?id=$1&name=$2&firstname=$3 [QSA,L]
```